# How can I use Linux/BSD `read` command to read some lines that happens in a time interval?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I want to use the Mac `fswatch` command to watch file changes and notify some auto compilation process to auto compile my files. Something like the following line:

```
fswatch src/* | (while read; do COMPILE; done)
```

The `src/*` is `rsync`ed from somewhere else, so `fswatch` will be notified multiple times when `src/*` changed.

I want the `COMPILE` command being called only once in one `rsync` procedure so I want to add some time limit for `read` command so that I can set a time interval, for example, 1 second, for `read` to process all the lines it receives in 1 second so the `COMPILE` command will not run many times when `rsync` is not completed.

Comment: `bash` has a `read -t 1` you can use to fail if no line is received within 1 second. You can do that until it fails to drain the events.

Comment: @that other guy Thanks!